# What are the properties of the QToolbar style that I can change?

Tags: css, qt, qt4, styling

I have a QToolbar which I have applied style to:

```
sMainWindowStyle += "QToolBar::handle { image: url(:/icons/toolbar_handle.png); }\n";
```

However as well as changing the toolbar's handle I want to change the expand arrow >>

I am unable to find a list of properties, so that I can look up what the toolbar expand arrow is.  Does anybody know of a definitive list of style properties in Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the expand button with the following CSS.

```css
QToolButton#qt_toolbar_ext_button 
{ 
    qproperty-icon: url(:/path/to/image.png);
}
```

Unfortunately the best way I know to find out which properties you can set, is to browse through the Qt source code. Some styles can even not support some properties, other styles do.